# Is it possible to make a shell function auto-complete a path by pressing tab?

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I have a very simple shortcut function for accessing project folders in my workspace:

```
function cdw() {
        cd ~/workspace/$1
}
```

I'd really love if I could get this to auto-complete the folder name.
Is it possible, if so, how can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Just make an alias out of it, then Zsh’s completion will handle it automatically:

```bash
alias cdw='cd ~/workspace; cd'
```

Comment: hmm... I can't get this to work

Comment: What error do you get?